# Trying to use GridSearchCV returning error: Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`

Tags: python, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to build a Voting Ensemble model, with a data transformation pipeline. I still need to put the transformation of the response variable into the pipeline. I'm trying to use GridSearchCV to evaluate the best parameters for each algorithm, but when I try to run the last code block, I get an error.

```
dummy= pd.get_dummies(df['over_30'])
df = pd.concat((df, dummy), axis = 1)
df = df.drop(['over_30','N'], axis = 1)
df = df.rename(columns = {'Y':'over_30'})

X,y = df.drop(['over_30'], axis = 1), df[['over_30']]

categorical = ['business_sector', "state"]
numerical = ['valor_contrato', 'prazo', 'num_avalistas', 'annual_revenue',
             'risk', 'carteira_vencer_curto_prazo', 'carteira_vencer_longo_prazo',
             'risk_fintech_fidc', 'risk_pos_money', 'alavancagem_rate', 'patrimonio_socios',
             'target_amount', 'score', 'pib', 'company_month', 'week_month']

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

variable_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numerical),
        ('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical)],
         remainder='passthrough')

classifiers = [
    XGBClassifier(),
    LGBMClassifier(),
    RandomForestClassifier()
]

xgbclassifier_parameters = {
    'classifier__eta' : [0.001,0.3],
    'classifier__gamma' : [0],
    'classifier__max_depth' : [3, 7],
    'classifier__grow_policy' : ['lossguide', 'deptwise'],
    'classifier__objective' : ['reg:logistic'],
    'classifier__reg_lambda' : [1.25, 1],
    'classifier__subsample' : [0.5, 0.6, 0.7],
    'classifier__tree_method' : ['auto', 'hist'],
    'classifier__colsample_bytree' : [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    'classifier__max_leaves' : [0, 7]
}

randomforest_paramenters = {
    'classifier__n_estimators': [200, 500],
    'classifier__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'classifier__max_depth': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
}

lightgbm_parameters = {
    'classifier__num_leaves': [31, 127],
    'classifier__reg_alpha': [0.1, 0.5],
    'classifier__min_data_in_leaf': [30, 50, 100, 300, 400],
    'classifier__lambda_l1': [0, 1, 1.5],
    'classifier__lambda_l2': [0, 1]
}

parameters = [
    xgbclassifier_parameters,
    randomforest_paramenters,
    lightgbm_parameters
]

estimators = []

# iterate through each classifier and use GridSearchCV
for i, classifier in enumerate(classifiers):
    # create a Pipeline object
    pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('transformer', variable_transformer),
        ('classifier', classifier)
    ])
    clf = GridSearchCV(pipe,
                       param_grid=parameters[i],
                       scoring=['f1_weighted', 
                                'f1_macro', 
                                'recall', 
                                'roc_auc',
                                'precision'],
                        refit='recall',
                       cv=8)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    print("Tuned Hyperparameters :", clf.best_params_)
    print("Recall:", clf.best_score_)
    # add the clf to the estimators list
    estimators.append((classifier.__class__.__name__, clf))
```

But when I run this last cell, i get this error:

```
min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100,
                       n_jobs=None, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
                       verbose=0, warm_start=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Is `auto` supported for `tree_method`? The doc says currently supported only if set it to `hist`, `approx` or `gpu_hist`.

Comment: @Priya I've tried to remove that value, but the error continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always, please post the stack trace of the error for people to understand**

There are multiple mistakes in your code,

1. You are creating Pipeline Object using `varible_transformer`, where are you fitting it?
2. What is `X` and `y`?

Solution:

1. Separate `X`-> input features needed for training and `y`-> the output variable values which the model has to learn.
2. Create pipeline object, it is a wrapper that does the preprocessing for you, so **fit it first** before giving the input features to model.
3. After fitting the pipeline object, you give the resultant numpy array to the classifier as the `X` and corresponding `y` to fit the model/classifier.

I am showing an example of regressors with the data that I had handy.

```
# median_house_value is what I am trying to estimate.
# input_features = ['longitude','latitude','housing_median_age','total_rooms','total_bedrooms','population','households','median_income']

df = pd.read_csv("/filepath/california_housing_train.csv")
X = df.drop("median_house_value", axis=1)
y = df["median_house_value"]

categorical = []
numerical = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'housing_median_age', 'total_rooms',
         'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'households',
         'median_income']

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

variable_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
    ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numerical),
    ('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical)],
     remainder='passthrough')
regressors = [XGBRegressor(),RandomForestRegressor()]

xgbregressor_parameters = { 
'regressor__grow_policy' : ['lossguide', 'deptwise'],
'regressor__objective' : ['reg:squarederror'],   
'regressor__colsample_bytree' : [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
'regressor__max_leaves' : [0, 7]}

 randomforest_parameters = {
'n_estimators': [200, 500],
'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
'max_depth': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}

parameters = [xgbregressor_parameters, randomforest_parameters]

estimators = []

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
('transformer', variable_transformer)])


# fit the pipeline with input features for preprocessing
prepared_data = pipe.fit_transform(X)

# iterate through each regressor and use GridSearchCV
for i, regressor in enumerate(regressors):   

    clf = GridSearchCV(regressor,
                   param_grid=parameters[i],
                   scoring=['neg_mean_squared_error', 
                            'r2', 
                            'explained_variance', 
                            ],
                    refit='neg_mean_squared_error',
                   cv=2)
clf.fit(prepared_data, y)
print("Tuned Hyperparameters :", clf.best_params_)

# add the clf to the estimators list    
estimators.append((regressor.__class__.__name__, clf))

# Output:
 
Tuned Hyperparameters : {'regressor__colsample_bytree': 0.7, 'regressor__grow_policy': 'lossguide', 'regressor__max_leaves': 0, 'regressor__objective': 'reg:squarederror'}
Tuned Hyperparameters : {'max_depth': 4, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'n_estimators': 200}
```

**Note**: Delete the `classifier` tag prepended to the parameter names for RandomForestclassifier in your case.